# Error while trying to install virtualenv for OpenCV for Python 3.6.5 on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos, opencv, virtualenv, python-3.6

I get the following error when I am trying to install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

/usr/local/bin/python3

/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON =/usr/local/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.

```
My bash profile is as follows:



 PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
    export PATH
    
    # add custom, local installations to PATH
    
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:"$PATH"
    
    # add MacPorts to PATH
    
    export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs

    export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/

    source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

and my PATH is:



/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
    
    I see that the virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper.sh are present in /usr/local/bin
```

This shows that i have the "virtualenv" installed in the following directory.

```
    MacBook-Air:bin jays$ ls -alt vir*
    -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    301 Jul  8 22:09 virtualenv-clone
   
     -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    325 Jul  8 22:09 virtualenv

    -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  41703 Feb  9  2019 virtualenvwrapper.sh
    
        -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin   2210 Feb  9  2019 virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh
    MacBook-Air:bin jays$ pwd
   
 /usr/local/bin
```

This is the directory listing to show my python directory:

MacBook-Air:bin jays$ ls -alt pyt*

I have python 3.6.5:

```
       lrwxr-xr-x  1 jays  admin  46 Jul  8 21:38 python3.6m-config -> ../Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/bin/python3.6m-config
        
        lrwxr-xr-x  1 jays  admin  39 Jul  8 21:38 python3.6m -> ../Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/bin/python3.6m
        
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jays  admin  45 Jul  8 21:38 python3.6-config -> ../Cella
r/python/3.6.5_1/bin/python3.6-config
        
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jays  admin  38 Jul  8 21:38 python3.6 -> ../Cella
r/python/3.6.5_1/bin/python3.6
        
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jays  admin  43 Jul  8 21:38 python3-config -> ../Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/bin/python3-config
        
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jays  admin  36 Jul  8 21:38 python3 -> ../Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/bin/python3

Any insight would be appreciated. I looked at similar questions which have been answered however the answers there did not resolve my issue.
```

Comment: Why ```bash_profile``` ? Shouldnt it be only ```profile```

Comment: That was the instruction on how to install opencv.